# PDO update statement not updating after adding second where clause

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I had this PDO update statement working fine for updating text until I added a second WHERE clause. After I added the post.SID=:SID the text no longer updates in mysql even though I get no errors. Is it possible that you can't have multiple WHERE clauses in PDO statements? Here is the text:

```
$current = $latestposition[0]['position'];
$this = $the_SID;

if(isset($_POST ['submit'])){

$formtext = $_POST['$contedit'];

$upda = 'UPDATE writing SET text=:text where snippets.SID=:SID and approved=:approved and position=:position';

$stmt = $dbh->prepare($upda);
$stmt->bindParam(':text', $formtext, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':SID', $this, PDO::PARAM_INT);  
$stmt->bindParam(':position', $current, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':approved', $z = Y, PDO::PARAM_STR);                                          
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: You are trying to use a table `post.` in your `WHERE` condition that does not exist in the query.

Comment: That is true, but not the problem here. I changed it to the correct table snippets in the query. Still no luck.

Comment: But the `snippets` table does not exist anywhere else in your query. That is incorrect sql syntax. What relationship does `snippets.SID` have with your table `writing` anyway?

Comment: are you sure it's `['$contedit'];` not `['contedit'];` ?

Comment: Just tried it both ways hans. Is my syntax for multiple WHERE clauses correct? All was well until I added the approved and snippets WHERE clauses

Comment: Why are you adding an unknown table in your `WHERE` clause? Is `SID` a column in your table `writing`? If yes, then it should just be `WHERE SID=:SID and approved=:approved and position=:position`. If `SID` is not in the `writing` table, you need to determine why you are adding a table/column that has no relationship with your actual table.

Comment: Got it. I just dropped the snippets table name altogether. SID=:SID is all I needed and it went. Much thanks.

Comment: And someone upvote hans $this comment